# Correct way to call function synchronously

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, synchronous

Let me start of by saying I know about async/await but I dont really want to include babel, it seems like to much trouble and I dont have any problem sticking with the promises. So what I am trying to do is pretty straightforward, 
basically achieve 'synchronous' flow in my function.

The code below gives me an unhandled exception. I'd like to hear any ideas why is that as well, if possible, whether I am on the right track here. If you have any questions please go ahead and ask.

```
function A()
{
    //...
    result = B();
    Promise.all(result).then(function(result){
        //after finishing B continue
    });
}

function B()
{
    //..
    C();
    return number;
}

function C()
{
    var data1;
    var data2;
    //..
    calling_DB = DB_get(..., function(result){ data1 = ..;});//callback cause I ma fetching data from DB
    Promise.all(data1).then(function(data1){
        calling_DB2 = DB_get(..., function(result){ data2 = ..;});
        Promise.all(data2).then(function(data2){
            //...
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: b doesn't return anything... and you don't need to call Promise.all() on a single promise, just call .then on said promise.

Comment: It does actually let me add something simple, the reason I removed is because thats not where the issue was/is

Comment: Right, you certainly can wrap every promise you make with Promise.all()... it's just completely unnecessary. you gain nothing.

Comment: wait... you removed the return, because *'that's not where the issue is/was'*? that makes no sense. You're doing `Promise.all(undefined)` currently due to not returning anything from `B`.

Comment: Okay, so how can I be sure that first the B will be executed and then the A will proceed?

Comment: You shouldn't mix callbacks and promises in the `DB_get()` calls. Also, an unhandled exception is exactly what the term suggests: an exception is thrown, and you're not handling it. So you should add error handling to your promise chain(s).

Comment: Edited my post, sorry I messed up when I tried to remove the unnecessary things, thats how it actually is.

Comment: ok, same problem... C doesn't return anything, and you're not doing anything with it that would allow A to wait on it. `Promise.all(5).then(...)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay I should call it with callback from B?, and about the return, if I dont want to return anything should I return a value like 1 or 0 to know it finished?

Comment: no... that won't help you know when it is finished. the return will happen long before it is finished. you would need to return a promise.

Comment: Could you please provide me a simple example, if possible

Comment: `function foo () {return Promise.resolve(5);}` Unfortunately though solving your problem will be a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: So I should change the promise.all, to resolve uh, and add a callback to B right? Since I am a bit new with the callbacks and such I was wondering if generally I have the right mindset

Comment: @KevinB would you perhaps want to go the chats, and briefly explain to me why it'd me complicated to solve my issue?

Comment: to your previous comment, no, resolve() is for creating a promise around something that isn't asynchronous, you'd need to create a new promise and then resolve it when it needs to be resolved. You need to find a tutorial on promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the below approach for calling those functions in the chain

```js
function A()
{
    return B()
        .then(function(_merged_db_get_results)
        {
            //after finishing B continue

            console.dir(_merged_db_get_results);

            return true;
        })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
            console.dir(error);
            return false;
        });
}

function B()
{
    return C()
        // Can be removed : START
        .then(function(_merged_db_get_results)
        {
            return _merged_db_get_results;
        });
        // Can be removed : END
}

function C()
{
    var db_1_res;

    return Promise.resolve(true)
        .then(function(_above_true)
        {
            return DB_get(condition);
        })
        .then(function(_db_get_results_1)
        {
            db_1_res = _db_get_results_1;

            return DB_get(condition);
        })
        .then(function(_db_get_results_2)
        {
            return [db_1_res, _db_get_results_2];
        });
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the initial Promise.resolve(true) just execute the required method, and pass that into the Promise.resolve. So long as the required methods have error handling in place and always return promises on error cases.

Comment: Agree. That was for explanation only. Else if we have Promisified functions then we can call them instead of Promise.resolve(true). :)

Comment: Coolios, just FYI really. Other benifit of your approach though Is any exceptions thrown in the wrapped methods will automatically be caught by the promise.

Comment: :) :) Thanks @ste2425 :)